# How to write Linq-To-SQL statment which is equal to my following TSQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

TSQL:-

```
Update table1
 Set Name = 'John',
     Address = null
where
 ID = 1
```

LINQ-TO-SQL

```
var tab = db.Table1.Single(s => s.ID == 3);
                tab.Name = DateTime.Now;
                tab.Address = null;
                db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var dataContext = new MyEntities())
{
    var contact = Contacts.Single (c => c.ContactID == 1);
    contact.FirstName = 'John';
    contact.Address= 'Toronto';
    dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a single LINQ to SQL statement for updates. You have to retrieve the object, modify it, then save the changes (code assumes a single row since you have a specific Id):

```
var entity = context.Table1.Single(t => t.Id == 1);

entity.Name = "John";
entity.Address = "Toronto";

context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Justin: this code converts to TSQL like this:- Update Set ....... where ID = 1 and Name = "John" and Address = "Toronto". (Ran SQL PRofiler)

Comment: @User13839404 - Yes, I was simply pointing out that it wasn't a single C# statement.